# Iterating thru Pandas DataFrame, multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

parsed_df

```
  student_name, course_id,  weight,
0   A   1   10
1   B   1   10
2   C   1   10
3   A   1   40
4   B   1   40
5   C   1   40
6   A   1   50
7   B   1   50
8   C   1   50
9   A   2   40
10  C   2   40
11  A   2   60
12  C   2   60
13  A   3   90
14  B   3   90
15  C   3   90
16  A   3   10
17  B   3   10
18  C   3   10
```

What's the best way to iterate thru for each student and course_id to summarize the weight of each course for each student? The return value of the weights should each add up to 100, if not it should return an error.

For example: calculated_df = parsed_df.groupby(['student_name','course_id'])['weight'].sum()

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide your desired output.

Comment: This seems like a `groupby` the student and course with `sum`

Comment: @SangkeunPark The desired output is the sum of the weights of each course for each student.

Comment: @G.Anderson, that is correct. How do I iterate thru the sums to check if they equal 100, and return an error if they do not?

Comment: What have you tried based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts?

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the sum to 100?

```
>>> df.groupby(['student_name', 'course_id'])['weight'].sum().eq(100).reset_index()

  student_name  course_id  weight
0            A          1    True
1            A          2    True
2            A          3    True
3            B          1    True
4            B          3    True
5            C          1    True
6            C          2    True
7            C          3    True
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'student_name': ['A', 'B',  'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'course_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'weight': [10, 10, 10, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 40, 40, 60, 60, 90, 90, 90, 10, 10, 9]
})

df = df.groupby(by=['student_name', 'course_id']).agg({'weight': 'sum'})
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(df)
#  student_name  course_id  weight
#0            A          1     100
#1            A          2     100
#2            A          3     100
#3            B          1     100
#4            B          3     100
#5            C          1     100
#6            C          2     100
#7            C          3      99 -> Intentionally adjusted to raise Exception

#To check if there is weight, which is not 100
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['weight'] != 100:
        raise Exception(f"Student {row['student_name']}\'s Course ID {row['course_id']}: {row['weight']}")
```

```
Exception: Student C's Course ID 3: 99
```